# oninput event attribute in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I'm building a series of input fields that automatically tab when their max length has been reached. This works by checking the length of the value on the `ng-keyup` event, but this has a slight problem that can be solved by using the `oninput` event instead. However, this does not seem to be present in Angular?

The problem I'm trying to solve:

When I rapidly enter the max amount of characters (two digits in my case, which can be entered quite fast) the first `keyup` fires after both characters are entered and tabs to the next field. The second `keyup` only registers after tabbing, so it fires on the next field. This causes unwanted behavior.

To reproduce check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ruwpoeo/2/) (jQuery, because it allows me to quickly reproduce both the problem and solution I'm looking for), fill in the "month" and "year" fields and then rapidly enter 2 digits in the "day" field. When done fast enough, the focus jumps all the way to "year" (because the second `keyup` was fired while "month" was in focus).

When using `.on('input', ...)` instead this problem disappears. However, I would like to use this not in jQuery but in Angular as an attribute, like `ng-keyup`. Is that possible, and if not how could I fix this problem in another way?

Comment: Is this inside a directive? You can just use `.on("input", ...)` inside the directive, no?

Comment: @RGraham I was not complete in my question, sorry. I would like to use an `ng-input="myCallback()"`-like attribute on an element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're using jquery in that jsfiddle. Instead in angular, to bind the `oninput` event, you can use:

Mostly this kind of DOM manipulation must go inside directive. Just for demo sake, am adding it to the controller:

```
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("input")).on("input", function (event) {

    var $input = angular.element(event.target),
        maxlength = $input.attr('max').length;

    if (this.value.length >= maxlength) {
        this.nextElementSibling.tagName==="INPUT" ? this.nextElementSibling.focus() : this.blur();
    }

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fizuyecipa/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: I'm using jQuery to show the problem and how I'd like to fix it (but using Angular instead), updated the question to make that more clear. I think I'm unable to use your answer, as I'd like to bind the event using an `ng-` attribute.

Comment: Check now, I've updated the answer with a demo. You need to place that code inside the appropriate controller. You can create a custom directive instead and bind the events via that.

Comment: This seems like a neat solution, I'd hoped for an attribute but by lack thereof this will have to do. I'll check if this works in my code.

Comment: Great. I've updated the `focus` event with some logic. Only if there is another `input` field present it will focus to that else it will just `blur`

Comment: The actual application I'm working on is a lot bigger and more complex, my example is very basic just to show the problem. Thanks anyway, I'll be able to work this in.